# Why do the hidden dividers come back up after mouse over?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

Why wont the code below behave as expected? PLEASE HELP! The effect should be similar to this: http://techweek.com/miami/techweek100/

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/edpKc/

```
var img = $('.grid-gallery section');
  if (img.length){
      img.on('mouseover',function(){
          $(this).find('.minibio').slideDown('fast')
 });

$(img).on('mouseout',function(){
   $(this).find('.minibio').slideUp('fast');
   });
 }
```

It seems to overreact, and toggle when I dont want it to. Thank you SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prabably want `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead:

```
img.on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).find('.minibio').slideDown('fast')
});

img.on('mouseleave',function(){
   $(this).find('.minibio').slideUp('fast');
});
```

You can see the difference between the events [here](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) under "Demo".

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to the wrong events, you'll have more joy with this:

```
if (img.length){
  img.on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).find('.minibio').slideDown('fast')
  });
  $(img).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.minibio').slideUp('fast');
  });
}
```

ref: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwLtl/